# How do I take this shape in Illustrator and curve it along an arc

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want this vector image:

[image]

To look like this:

[image]

See the way it bends along the top arc? I have tried Warp, but it didn't give it the uniform thickness all the way around.

Comment: Typical. After many many tries, I found Envelope Distort > Make Warp and it gave me a desired effect. 

It doesn't look perfect, but it's close. Still interested to hear other ideas from some more seasoned users.

Answer (score 0):

As I know you can only use "**warp > arc**" effect or you can try duplicate and rotate method ([There is a tutorial for it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YF46iEiAEvY)), if this is not work for you, you should re-drew that shape like in the sketch.

Answer (score -1):

I would use the effects options in the Appearance palette to apply an "arc" effect. [image: attached] This way the angle of the arc is editable, as is your group of shapes. Does this address your concern of the shape bending along the top arc?

Answer (score -2):

Try making a brush and then adding the brush to a circle. I think this would do the trick :)